# PHP not showing anything

Tags: php

I cannot see anything when on my xampp server and displays an empty page. I am trying to find the error but failed. anyone can help would be appreciated

here is class.db.php

```
<?php
        class db {
            private $conn;
            private $host;
            private $user;
            private $password;
            private $baseName;
            private $port;
            private $Debug;

            function __construct($params=array()) {
                $this->conn = false;
                $this->host = 'localhost'; //hostname
                $this->user = 'root'; //username
                $this->password = ''; //password
                $this->baseName = 'db'; //name of your database
                $this->debug = true;
                $this->connect();
            }

            function __destruct() {
                $this->disconnect();
            }

            function connect() {
                if (!$this->conn) {
                    try {
                        $this->conn = new PDO('mysql:host='.$this->host.';dbname='.$this->baseName.'', $this->user, $this->password, array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8'));  
                    }
                    catch (Exception $e) {
                        die('Erreur : ' . $e->getMessage());
                    }

                    if (!$this->conn) {
                        $this->status_fatal = true;
                        echo 'Connection BDD failed';
                        die();
                    }
                    else {
                        $this->status_fatal = false;
                    }
                }

                return $this->conn;
            }

            function disconnect() {
                if ($this->conn) {
                    $this->conn = null;
                }
            }

            function getOne($query) {
                $result = $this->conn->prepare($query);
                $ret = $result->execute();
                if (!$ret) {
                   echo 'PDO::errorInfo():';
                   echo '<br />';
                   echo 'error SQL: '.$query;
                   die();
                }
                $result->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                $reponse = $result->fetch();

                return $reponse;
            }

            function getAll($query) {
                $result = $this->conn->prepare($query);
                $ret = $result->execute();
                if (!$ret) {
                   echo 'PDO::errorInfo():';
                   echo '<br />';
                   echo 'error SQL: '.$query;
                   die();
                }
                $result->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                $reponse = $result->fetchAll();

                return $reponse;
            }

            function execute($query) {
                if (!$response = $this->conn->exec($query)) {
                    echo 'PDO::errorInfo():';
                   echo '<br />';
                   echo 'error SQL: '.$query;
                   die();
                }
                return $response;
            }
        }
```

and index.php has at the top above `<!doctype`

```
<?PHP
    include('db.class.php');
    $bdd = new db();
    ?>
```

along my html code

Comment: Are all the files in the same folder? Also, change it from `<?PHP` to `<?php`. Turn on your error reporting at the top of your page with - `ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(-1);`

Comment: white screen of death: error checking\display are off, turn them on to see the error. at the top of your php page add: `ini_set('display_errors', 'On'); ini_set('html_errors', 0); error_reporting(-1);`

Comment: Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\project\db.class.php on line 85

Answer (score 1):

You just created an instance of this class, this only triggered the constructor, you did not make any calls to functions, so nothing shows on that page.

For the future: enable displaying errors by adding

```
ini_set('display_errors',1);
```

this will help you to find and correct errors.

Comment: inside your file, below <? opening tag

Comment: Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\project\db.class.php on line 85